# param is not accepting orderBy: 'startTime'?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, google-api

Hi I am writing an AngularJS in TypeScript with Google API trying to make a call to get google calendar events, the syntax is defined in documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
but for some reason `gapi.client.calendar.events.list(params)`

does not accept a parameter `orderBy: 'startTime'`

```
getCalendarEvents() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list().then(response => {
        let calendars = response.result.items;
        if (calendars === undefined) return [];
        console.log(calendars);
        let requests = calendars.map(calendar => {
            //let params = { calendarId: calendar.id, timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(), showDeleted: false, singleEvents: true, maxResults: 10 };
            let params = { 
                calendarId: calendar.id, 
                timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(), 
                showDeleted: false, 
                singleEvents: true, 
                orderBy: 'startTime' };
            return gapi.client.calendar.events.list(params).then(response => {
                console.log(response.result.items);
                let events: any = response.result.items.sort((a, b) => { // sorting array of events by date
                    if (a.start.date) a.start['newdate'] = a.start.date;
                    if (b.start.date) b.start['newdate'] = b.start.date;
                    if (a.start.dateTime) a.start['newdate'] = a.start.dateTime.slice(0, 10);
                    if (b.start.dateTime) b.start['newdate'] = b.start.dateTime.slice(0, 10);
                    if (a.start['newdate'] > b.start['newdate']) return 1;
                    if (a.start['newdate'] < b.start['newdate']) return -1;
                    return 0;
                });
                return events.map(event => {
                    let calendarEvent: CalendarEvent = {
                        title: event.summary,
                        htmlLink: event.htmlLink,
                        start: new Date(event.start.date == undefined ? event.start.dateTime == undefined ? '' : event.start.dateTime : event.start.date),
                        end: new Date(event.end.date == undefined ? event.end.dateTime == undefined ? '' : event.end.dateTime : event.end.date),
                        allDay: false,
                        color: calendar.backgroundColor
                    };
                    return calendarEvent;
                });

            });
        });
        return this.$q.all(requests);
    });
}
```

**Why is this not working ??**

> file: 'file:///d%3A/Projects/Homepage2/app/google.service.ts'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'Argument of type '{ calendarId: string;
>   timeMin: string; showDeleted: boolean; singleEvents: boolean; orderBy:
>   stri...' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'EventsListParameters'.   Types of property 'orderBy' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"startTime" | "updated" | undefined'.' at: '166,61' source: 'ts'

where params is defined like this:

```
  interface EventsListParameters {
    calendarId: string;
    alwaysIncludeEmail?: boolean;
    iCalUID?: string;
    maxAttendees?: integer;
    maxResults?: integer;
    orderBy?: EventsOrder;
    pageToken?: string;
    privateExtendedProperty?: string;
    q?: string;
    sharedExtendedProperty?: string;
    showDeleted?: boolean;
    showHiddenInvitations?: boolean;
    singleEvents?: boolean;
    syncToken?: SyncToken;
    timeMax?: datetime;
    timeMin?: datetime;
    timeZone?: string;
    updatedMin?: datetime;
  }
```

and EventsOrder is defined like this:

```
  type EventsOrder =
    // Order by the start date/time (ascending). This is only available when querying single events (i.e. the parameter singleEvents is True)
    'startTime' |
    // Order by last modification time (ascending).
    'updated';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fix

Change `orderBy: 'startTime'` to `orderBy: 'startTime' as 'startTime'`

## More

It is inferrred as a string. Here I used as assertion to force it to be inferred a literal.

- Docs on type assertion https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html
- Trick mentioned here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html